# Split command output into separate variables

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to use a bash script with macos time machine.

I'm trying to read the properties of the time machine backup destinations and then split the destinations into variables if there are multiple destinations.

from there I can use the ID to make a backup.

I'm having trouble splitting the output into their own variables.

```
rawdstinfo=$(tmutil destinationinfo)
echo "$rawdstinfo"

> ==================================================
Name          : USB HDD
Kind          : Local
Mount Point   : /Volumes/USB HDD
ID            : 317BD93D-7D90-494C-9D5F-9013B25D1345
====================================================
Name          : TM TEST
Kind          : Local
Mount Point   : /Volumes/TM TEST
ID            : 4648083B-2A11-42BC-A8E0-D95917053D27
```

I was thinking of counting the `==================================================` and then trying to split the variable based on them but i'm not having any luck.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

PS:
to make it clear what i would like to achieve, I would like to send each destination drive to an object. From there I can compare the mount point names (which has been selected earlier in the script), to then get the "destination ID" within that object so I can then use it with the other tmutil commands such as

```
#start a TM backup
sudo tmutil startbackup --destination $DESTINATIONID

#remove Migration HDD as a destination
sudo tmutil removedestination $DESTINATIONID
```

Comment: Something like `echo $rawdstinfo | grep "ID" | cut -d" " -f3` might work, but @LéaGris has suggested a better approach that is less likely to fail - it depends on what you're attempting to do with the data. If you can supply some example input/expected output in your question, and include the things you've already tried, you will likely get more helpful responses

Comment: Accordingly to https://ss64.com/osx/tmutil.html the `destinationinfo` command has a `-X` option to output the result as XML. XML is a reliable structure to be parsed with a proper parser like xmlstarlet, or an xslt processor like xsltproc. tmutil may return multiple destinations, not clear how you inted to process these informations.

Comment: @aqueries : From your question, it is unclear which information exactly should go into which variable. Also, show your own attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use awk for parsing delimited flat files.  I copied the tmutil output from your question and pasted it into a file I named testdata.txt since I'm not doing this on a Mac.  Make sure the number of equal signs in the record separators actually match what tmutil produces.

Here is the awk portion of the solution which goes into a file I named timemachine_variables.awk:

```
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
function trim(s)  { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }
BEGIN {
    RS="====================================================\n";
    FS=":|\n"
}
{
i=FNR-1 
}
(FNR>1 && $1 ~ /Name/) {print "Name["i"]="trim($2)}
(FNR>1 && $3 ~ /Kind/) {print "Kind["i"]="trim($4)}
(FNR>1 && $5 ~ /Mount Point/) {print "Mount_Point["i"]="trim($6)}
(FNR>1 && $7 ~ /ID/) {print "ID["i"]="trim($8)}
```

The functions at the beginning are to trim leading or trailing white spaces off any fields.  I split the records based on the equals sign separators and the fields based on the colon ":" character.  FNR is gawk's internal variable for the current record number that we're looking at.  Since the output apparently begins with a bar of equal signs, the first record is empty so I am using FNR > 1 as a condition to exclude it.  Then I have gawk print code which will become array assignments for bash.  In your example, this should be gawk's output:

```
$ gawk -f timemachine_variables.awk testdata.txt
Name[1]=USB HDD
Kind[1]=Local
Mount_Point[1]=/Volumes/USB HDD
ID[1]=317BD93D-7D90-494C-9D5F-9013B25D1345
Name[2]=TM TEST
Kind[2]=Local
Mount_Point[2]=/Volumes/TM TEST
ID[2]=4648083B-2A11-42BC-A8E0-D95917053D27
```

In your BASH script, declare the arrays from the gawk script's output:

```
$ declare $(gawk -f timemachine_variables.awk testdata.txt)
```

You should now have BASH arrays for each drive:

```
$ echo ${ID[2]}
4648083B-2A11-42BC-A8E0-D95917053D27
```

UPDATE: The original awk script that I posted does not work on the Mac because BSD awk does not support multi-character separators.  I'm leaving it here because it works for gawk, and comparing the two scripts may help others who are looking for a way to achieve multi-character separator behavior in BSD awk.

Instead of changing the default record separator which is the end of the line, I set my own counter of i to 0, and then increment it every time the whole record starts and ends with one or more equal signs.  Since awk now views each line as its own record and the field separator is still ":", the name we are trying to match is always in $1 and the value is always in $2.

```
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
function trim(s)  { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }
BEGIN {
    FS=":";
    i=0;
}
($0 ~ /^=+$/) {i++;}
($1 ~ /Name/) {print "Name["i"]="trim($2)}
($1 ~ /Kind/) {print "Kind["i"]="trim($2)}
($1 ~ /Mount Point/) {print "Mount_Point["i"]="trim($2)}
($1 ~ /ID/) {print "ID["i"]="trim($2)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You have used gawk. MacOS doesn't come with gawk by default. Only awk, therefore your answer does not work. I would like to try maximise the portability of the script by using only internally available commands without having to install anything extra.

Comment: True, but I suspect that I have not used any gawk-specific extensions.  You might be able to run it in awk on the Mac without any changes.  I thought about testing it myself, but I'm on a Linux machine right now where awk is symlinked to gawk.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. command ```awk -f timemachine_variables.awk testdata.txt``` outputs nothing on a mac.

Comment: My best guess without looking at this on a Mac is that your file has different line ending characters from mine.  Since my testdata.txt is just a copy/paste from your question, it would have LF line endings.  tmutil may have produced CR line endings.  Try changing line 6 of the awk script to FS=":|[\r\n]+"

Comment: Disregard the previous comment.  I just learned BSD awk on the Mac doesn't support multiple character record separators.  This would have to be done differently.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a new awk script which should work on the Mac.  I dusted off a machine running El Capitan, and it worked there.